# Does TCP slow down server and other clients for MMO game

Tags: mmo, server, client

hi guys i made a server and client for mmorpg game of course very amateurish. i am using UDP to send coordinates if the packet is lost doesnt matter i am already sending 10 times in a second. UDP doesn't slow down server and server doesn't slow down other clients. But i also want to use TCP for ID PW and attack skill because when i use attack skill he needs to go absolutely to server. If i use TCP for them, Will client1 slow down Server ? or Will Server slow down other clients ?

i am using c++,opengl,SDL 1.2 and SDL_net 1.2

I will be grateful for your help :)

[image]

EDIT I ADD VIDEO :D : youtu.be/J7Ulh4vUBu0 when only udp server loop 658982 in a second like at the end of the video if i add tcp this valuse slow down ?

Comment: At a low level, if you're using blocking sockets, a malicious or slow client will cause issues with your server. If you're using non-blocking sockets then your server can continue to do things even if a client hasn't responded (which is good in your case because it needs to continue to simulate the game!). At a higher level, your game code should probably make sure that if the client gives intent to do something, you aren't waiting for a client response to pull the trigger. Move as much logic as you can to your server.

Comment: Never even consider TCP for MMOs.

Comment: thanks your answers but i didn't understand completely i think i need to search blocking sockets and non blocking sockets :D

Comment: youtu.be/J7Ulh4vUBu0 when only udp server loop 658982 in a second like at the end of the video if i add tcp this valuse slow down ?

Answer (score 2):

TCP is generally viewed as being slow because of the guarantee of delivery, and the guarantee of delivery *in order*. When the packet is not received, it has to be resent. It seems that the [delay to resend the packet is implementation dependant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12956804/637987). If a packet is missing, the software will have to wait for that packet to continue it's process, even if the following packets have arrived.

This represents a potentially high delay.

So to answer your question: I guess it depends on how you implement your transmission layer (blocking vs non-blocking sockets), and I think this is independent of whether you used TCP or UDP.

The TCP vs UDP is not about *slowing down* the server or the client, it's about having the user experience lag or not.

IMHO, you could use TCP for ID and PW if you want, but I'd suggest to find another way using UDP to transmit your attack commands.

---

Disclaimer: I'm not an expert on the topic, I've just been reading a lot on it lately.

Comment: thanks your answers but i didn't understand completely i think i need to search blocking sockets and non blocking sockets :D

Comment: Yeah, blocking sockets are bad :P

Comment: i will upload youtube my project and i will show what i want let me 5 10 min

Comment: https://youtu.be/J7Ulh4vUBu0 when only udp server loop 658982 in a second like at the end of the video if i add tcp this valuse slow down ?

Comment: What is that value?

Comment: server loop value at a 1 second

Comment: You mean that the server loops 658982 times per second when you use TCP, and you wonder if that number will drop if you use UDP instead?

Comment: when i use UDP server main while function is making 658982 loops (only coordinate udp ) and i want to add TCP attack function and client1 use attack skill then client1 will send 1 tcp packet to server and what will happen main loop value if 658982 will down 1000 or 10000 so bad for me :d sorry for my so bad english

Comment: @EmreKaya That's not exactly how you should consider your architecture's performance. Most likely, you're using SDLNet in a non-blocking way. If you use TCP instead of UDP, maybe the number of loops per second will drop, maybe not, but that's not what is important. Game servers usually run at 20-30Hz, not at that high frame rate. When you'll use TCP, the time it takes from sending the information from your client to the server will increase, on average. The processing time will likely be the same.

Comment: @EmreKaya I will add here that you're not exactly doing 'real tests' because you're working only on your computer, in a closed loop, without having the chance to loose packet over the internet.

Comment: thank you for your attention i will read your messages again after i search blocking non blocking sockets and other my weaknesses and i will try to run client another computer from another internet

Comment: @EmreKaya Take a look at the SDLNet documentation, it tells you when a function call is blocking or non-blocking :)